# Reference multiple fields with aggregation function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have some mongo DB query which returns following two documents. (I am using aggregation & projection which returns me this result set).

```
{
    "name" : {
        "value" : "ANDERSON"
    },
    "ID" : {
        "value" : "2356"
    },
}

{
    "employeename" : {
        "value" : "DAVID"
    },
    "ID" : {
        "value" : "2356"
    },
}
```

My DB is schema less & I am storing attributes and there values. There are multiple attributes which represents the same information. For e.g. here "name" & "employeename" represents the same thing. I want the final output in some common attribute (say "Employee Name"). This common attribute can have value either from "name" or "employeename".

I think this problem can be solved by adding one more pipe in with the aggregation. I tried $or (it returns true/false not the value)

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
    { "$project" : { 
        "name" : 1, 
        "ID" : 1, "employeename" : 1 
    }},
    { "$project":{
        "Employee Name": {$or : ["$name", "$employeename"]}
    }} 
])
```

**Final Output should be**

```
{
    " Employee Name" : {
        "value" : "ANDERSON"
    },
    "ID" : {
        "value" : "2356"
    },
}

{
    " Employee Name" : {
        "value" : "DAVID"
    },
    "ID" : {
        "value" : "2356"
    },
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to write this mongo DB command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator, you can also shorten your pipeline to one `$project` stage.

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
    { "$project" : { 
        "EmployeeName" : { "$ifNull": [ "$name",  "$employeename" ] },
        "ID" : 1,
    }}
])
```